# Functional static typed languages and parallel computation

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

It seems to me that statically typed, and functional languages are perfect for parallel computation. Since asserting strong type constraints such as the functional purity of functions should be easy. And additionally, these programming languages are already well suited for the types of computation-heavy programs that would trivially benefit from data parallelism.

However, it seems that beyond Haskell, none of the other strongly typed functional languages support OS-level threads to back their parallelism. Is it actually the case that Haskell is the only language that supports this sort of thing in the modern day, and that any of the ML series languages, don't provide good threading support among other statically typed language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Frege](https://github.com/Frege), you can use the fork/join Java API, here is a blog post covering it: http://fregepl.blogspot.de/2011/09/parallelism-in-frege-employing-forkjoin.html

Comment: This is an interesting language, the threading support is still pretty minor, but accepting as it seems to be a close alternative.

Additionally, I've found that the language Rust, while in very alpha status, has some very interesting parallel computation models.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Haskell, but I know that Erlang deals pretty well with concurrency. However, Erlang is a dynamically typed language and the concurrency is handled in the programming language and not in the operating system.

It is suited for parallel programming as it creates sets of parallel processes that may interact via message passing without requiring the use of locks.

For those who are not familiar with Erlang, here is the [link](http://www.erlang.org/faq/introduction.html) for the language introduction.

There is also Scala, which integrates features of functional programming and object oriented programming. Scala runs on the Java VM and the threads communicate using an event-based model. This may be an indicator of the OS-level threads that you are looking for. Furthermore, it has built-in support for the [actor model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model).

There is a [book](http://www.pragprog.com/titles/vsscala/programming-scala) about Scala and multicore systems that you should take a look.

Comment: Yeah, erlang is very strongly a statically typed language, and the strong actor-model threading pushes other models of threading to the back-seat.

Comment: @Arelius I've updated my answer to include Scala, which may fit your purpose ;)

Comment: I don't mean os level threads in that there needs to be a one->one correlation, for instance, Erlang is suitable in this regard because while it does manage it's own threads in the OS. it also uses os threads in the backend to take advantage of multiple processors. My main point with that is to differentiate it from what's common in OCaml, and some Scheme's where they only support language level threading, and no SMP at all.

Comment: @Arelius I'm only familiar with languages where threading is supported at the OS level. And with those, you can "easily" think in parallelism. I agree with you that language level threading affects parallelism in their own way.